# Why are generators faster?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I understand that generators are faster than iterators.  I also understand that generators  can be implemented using `for` loop syntax.  For example:

```
    import time 


startT = time.time()


def myGen(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield x         


def myIter(n):
    for i in range(n):
        pass

def main():
    n=100
    startT=time.time()
    myIter(n)
    print 'myIter took ', time.time() - startT

    startT=time.time()
    myGen(n)
    print 'myGen(n) took ', time.time() - startT
```

This is just one example of the results:

```
myIter took 0.09234782
myGen(n) took 0.017847266
```

Since this uses the `for` loop syntax, then I don't understand how it is faster than an iterator.  This  generator uses an iterator, because the  "for" loop is implemented using an iterator.  If you time these, the generator is consistently faster.  Why is this, when the generator uses an iterator?

Thanks.

Comment: "I understand that generators are faster than iterators." - they're not. Why do you think they are? Generators are a kind of iterator.

Comment: Generators are not faster than iterators. Generators *are* iterators. Usually generator functions are actually **slower**, but more memory efficient.

Comment: It's not clear what code you believe that this is faster than. Could you include that in your question?

Comment: And could you include your timing code?

Comment: also `printing` variables to standard output slows down applications too.

Comment: First, you only did one test run instead of thousands. Second, `time.time()` isn't an accurate timer. Third, the generator only _creates_ the loop and does one iteration, while the other function creates the loop and then _iterates through the entire loop_.

Comment: consider using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) for measuring time of algorithms, and measure time of running the code many times (e.g. 1000), not just once

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your code, `myIter(n)` actually does work -- it loops 100 times.

`myGen(n)`, on the other hand, simply builds the generator -- and that's it.  It doesn't count to 100.  All you're doing is timing how long it takes to build the object, and you're timing it in an unreliable way.  If we use `timeit` (here using IPython to make things simpler):

```
>>> %timeit myIter(100)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1 µs per loop
>>> %timeit myGen(100)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 163 ns per loop
>>> %timeit myGen(10**1000)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 163 ns per loop
```

And we see that the `myGen(n)` time is independent of `n`, because it's not doing anything.  In fact, we can see your code was never executed another way:

```
>>> list(myGen(100))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-11-dd43d937402a>", line 1, in <module>
    list(myGen(100))
  File "<ipython-input-1-ba968e48e9fd>", line 3, in myGen
    yield x
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

If we fix this typo, and then try a fast way to consume the generator, we get something like

```
>>> %timeit myIter(100)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1 µs per loop
>>> %timeit consume(myGen(100), 100)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.44 µs per loop
```

and the generator version is slower, as is often the case.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have defined two functions: `myGen` and `myIter`, and you want to compare their performance. `myGen` is a generator function, and `myIter` is a regular loop. Let's analyze the performance of both functions.

1. `myGen` is a generator function, and it yields a value `x` in a loop. However, you haven't defined what `x` is in your code. I assume it's a variable you haven't shown in your provided code.
2. `myIter` is a regular loop that iterates `n` times but doesn't perform any specific operation inside the loop.

In terms of performance comparison:

- `myIter` will typically be faster because it's just a simple loop without any additional overhead of creating and managing generator objects.
- `myGen` involves the creation of a generator object and yields a value, which requires some additional overhead. Generators are useful when you need lazy evaluation or when you want to save memory by not generating all values at once. However, in this specific case, the generator doesn't provide any advantage over a simple loop.

Here's the modified code with some corrections:

```py
import time

def myGen(n, x):
    for i in range(n):
        yield x

def myIter(n):
    for i in range(n):
        pass

def main():
    n = 100
    x = 42  # Define the value to yield in myGen
    startT = time.time()
    myIter(n)
    print('myIter took', time.time() - startT)

    startT = time.time()
    list(myGen(n, x))  # Consume the generator with a list to measure its performance
    print('myGen(n) took', time.time() - startT)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In this code, we define the value `x`, which is passed to `myGen`. We also use `list(myGen(n, x))` to consume the generator in order to measure its performance properly.

In general, for simple operations like the ones you've shown, regular loops are faster than generators. Generators are more useful when you have a large dataset or when you want to perform lazy evaluation.